# Redirecting domains to another and append redirected domain as query string

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-parameters, domain-forwarding

I have the following in my htaccess file which forwards all domains pointing to this location to somedomain.uk which is working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.somedomain\.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somedomain.uk$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is there a way to pass the redirecting domain to `somedomain.uk` as a parameter.

e.g. going to example.com would then redirect to `https://www.somedomain.uk/?url=example.com`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure that is possible:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.somedomain\.uk$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.somedomain.uk%{REQUEST_URI}?url=%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301]
```

I would however suggest to use another parameter name, since a host name is *not* a "url".

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you @arkasha for your example and explanation! If I enter 0g.co.uk which points to the correct directory, it's got me as far as redirecting me to: https://0g.co.uk/?domain=0g.co.uk and then states that the connection is not private. I'm not entirely sure why this is happening as it was working fine before... Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Oh I've also noticed that it appends it for the main domain also. So if that were somedomain.uk it becomes somedomain.uk/?domain=somedomain.uk

Comment: The condition only rules out the host name "www.somedomain.uk". The hostname "somdomain.uk" is something else. If you also want to rule out that one then use a pattern like this `!^(www\.)?somedomain\.uk$`.

Comment: The issue with "the connection is not private" is most likely triggered because the original request is made via https while the redirection is implemented using the http protocol, just as you suggested in your own example. Such redirection will indeed get blocked for very good reasons. You will need to change the redirection rule to redirect to the https protocol too which obviously also means that you need to have a valid certificate installed for the target http host.

Comment: Hi @arkascha it was as stated. The change in protocol. All sorted now! Thank you very much for your assistance with this.